# CFTC CPO Exemptions

Tags: regulation

What are the exceptions set by the [CFTC](http://www.cftc.gov/) which exempt [Commodity Pool Operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodity_Pool_Operator) (CPO) from registering as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.hedgefundlawblog.com/hedge-fund-cpo-exemptions.html